How use SendKeys for send Up/Down arrow from main keyboard, not from numpad in VBA Excel?
I'm trying fill up web form by data from Excel byVBA.
I have a problem with movement on form's items by arrow keys.
Web form accept only arrow keys from main keyboard, arrow keys from numpad are used for scrolling form.
Application.SendKeys("{DOWN}") or keybd_event(VK_DOWN,0,0,0) from Lib "user32" "sending" numpad arrow down...
How send down arrow from main keyboard ? Is it possible?
Thanks
Jerry

{up} and {down} are the arrow keys in SendKeys, there is no distinction between numpad alterate arrow keys or the native arrow keys. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/sendkeys-statement

yes, I know, but on my laptop some difference is... Using numpad arrows scrolling object screen, keyboard arrows selecting cells in web form. Maybe some browser - Chrome - interpretation?

arrow keys from numpad are used for scrolling form. that is when the numslock is off. Othereise as @ChrisSchaller mentioned, there i sno difference.

Option 1 Check if using APIs solves the issue? Maube you do not need to use Sendkeys. Option 2 Check if nums lock is on or off. If it is off then switch is on and then use the SendKeys("{DOWN}")

Standard behaivor (no send keys, manaully) in web browser :Numlock ON -> keyboard arrows selecting cells in form, numpad writing numbers; Numlock OFF -> keyboard arrows select cells in form, numpad arrows scrolling form. What do you mean using API? Same behavior when I use keybd_event from user32 lib.

Use the Tab key to walk through controls.
Out of this solution
Numpad keys are controlled by keyboard hardware (BIOS Setup settings can be involved, additional control keys on the keyboard as well). Then they can be managed by HID driver. Also, not all key codes are available for SendKeys.
Arrow keys and Numpad arrow keys emit the same codes, but operating system tracks the Num lock switch to distinguish them. You should do the same plus to control the Num lock switch.

How is it going?
